OpenLayers - disable control that includes clicks on the map
In my project I have several controls that interact via clicking on the map so I have to deactivate them selectively to use one at a time.
What is the correct method to deactivate a control that involves a click event in the map?
Just do:
map.removeControl(overlayPopup)

Or do I also need to do:
map.un('singleclick' , eventName)

My doubt is this:
If I remove only the control without also removing the click event, will the event code run the same but idle, taking up resources? Or is the resource occupation so minimal that I don't have to worry about removing the click event too?
My Overlay
    var overlayPopup = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container
    });
    map.addOverlay(overlayPopup)

My Event Popup features with click - inserts data into overlayPopup
function onSingleClickFeatures(evt) {
    if (doHover || sketch) {
        return;
    }
    if (!featuresPopupActive) {
        featuresPopupActive = true;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var popupField;
    var currentFeature;
    var currentFeatureKeys;
    var clusteredFeatures;
    var popupText = '<ul>';
    
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        if (layer && feature instanceof ol.Feature && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") === undefined)) {
            var doPopup = false;

map.on('singleclick', onSingleClickFeatures)

My Event Popup wms with click - inserts data into overlayPopup
    function onSingleClickWMS(evt) {
        if (doHover || sketch) {
            return;
        }
        if (!featuresPopupActive) {
            popupContent = '';
        }
        var coord = evt.coordinate;
        var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
        var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    
        for (var i = 0; i < wms_layers.length; i++) {
            if (wms_layers[i][1] && wms_layers[i][0].getVisible()) {
                var url = wms_layers[i][0].getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
                    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection, {
                        'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
                    });
                if (url) {  

map.on('singleclick', onSingleClickWMS);


From your code it's not clear what is the connection between control and map single click event. Is map click event processing defined within your control? Please edit you question with more code/info.

I have included 2 examples related to my project, thanks.

In what way is this map click processing related to your several controls?

When I use onSingleClickFeatures and onSingleClickWMS I acquire the data and bring it into the ol.Overlay element, but if I use another control such as the measurement tool that involves clicks I don't know which is the right way to deactivate the above.

I admit I'm lost here about what the question is.

To deactivate the popup or the measurement tool, or the drawing tool that involve clicks on the map, is it better to remove only the control or also the click event that passes the data to the control?

Without all the relevant code I can't answer.

Thanks anyway, I can't explain myself better, I would have to insert hundreds of lines of code. Simply: I have a click event raised with map.on('singleclick', ...) and this event calls a function that puts data into an openlayers control. To deactivate everything, should I remove only the control or also the click event?
